# Why can we split the contour of a triangle into 4 other contours in the proof of Gousart's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

In the definition of the sum of smooth curves, the end of one curve must coincide with the origin of the other in order for the sum to be well-defined.
In the proof of Gousart's theorem, the triangle is split up into 4 smaller ones, but I don't see how they can be glued together without the lifting of the pencil.

The only thing I kind of see is that the interior segments are oriented in opposite ways for the different triangles, so I guess they nullify each other, and thus only the contour of the big triangle remains.
What am I missing?

Comment: Yes, inners cancel. Once one of the four triangles is oriented, the other three have each only one orientation so as to make inner sides of opposite orientation. [so you're not missing anything...]

Comment: My problem is that a curve is defined as a continuous function from an interval, and so when joining two curves they need to glue together. But I don't see how one can glue those triangles.

Comment: Gousart $\to$ Goursat.

Comment: Why would you need not to lift your pencil ? When you write $\int_{\gamma_1+\gamma_2+...}=\int_{\gamma_1}+\int_{\gamma_2}+...$, you don't need to have $\gamma_1, \gamma_2,...$ connected.

Comment: Perhaps, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9reG.png)? The sum of the integrals along the perimeters of the black and green triangles plus the integral along the perimeter of the red triangle equals the integral along the perimeter of the larger black triangle since the integrals along the red edges cancel the integrals along the green edges.